# Call a function by its REST API URL in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

I don't know if this is possible directly (of course, there are other, and far messier ways to do this), but I wish to be able to call a function by its URL in Spring Boot.

For example, say I have a `@RestController` and within that rest controller a function that looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", produces = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String myRequest(@RequestParam("request") String request) {
    return request;
}
```

What I would like to be able to do is have a user pass in a relative URL for a different endpoint of my API, and my code will call that portion of the api. For instance:

```
// Pass in "/otherRequest/SomeInfo"
@RequestMapping(value = "/", produces = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String myRequest(@RequestParam("request") String request) {
    //Goes to the function that handles "/otherRequest/SomeInfo"
    // and returns its value
    return callSomeFunctionByURL(request);
}
```

I realize that I can parse the string and go through a bunch of conditionals to get my result, but is there a more *Springy* way of doing this - like by calling `callSomeFunctionByURL`, or would I just have to do it the old way? (For those wondering why this situation would even happen, this is a theoretical question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, you should move your business logic to the *service* layer to use transactions around them.

In some cases you do some sophisticated logic on the view layer that is possible to use beans that you could create or inject to the controller to use in many controller methods and return results.

If this logic is not handled by the controller classes then it should be moved to another layer called a *presentation* layer. This layer is not covered by Spring, so you should do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use redirect and forward

Instead of

```
return request;
```

change it to

```
return "redirect:"+request;
```

or

```
return "forward:"+request;
```

**EDIT**

return `new ModelAndView(request)` if the controller is `RestController`

Comment: When I do this, my server simply return "forward:/someUrl/". I am guessing that is not expected behavior. Am I missing something?

Comment: Does `ModelAndView` only do `POST` requests? How can I have it do a `GET` or even a `PUT`?